# How to use 301 redirects to drive traffic to URLS with the same domain and sub domain (www and non-www subdomain)

Tags: .htaccess

I need to force https without www and with removal of extension .html.
The code I am using in htaccess throws an SEO error.

```
# BEGIN GD-SSL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^education\.mekan\-turk\.com$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300"
</IfModule>
# END GD-SSL

# BEGIN add SSL to http and www.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
# END add SSL to http and www.

# BEGIN Remove .html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
# END Remove .html
```

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: What is this: RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^education\.mekan\-turk\.com$

Comment: SEO reports flags warning that I need to "use 301 redirects to drive traffic to URLS with the same domain and sub domain"

Comment: What tool is producing this SEO report?

Comment: seobility.net - the free check returned: "Use 301 redirects to drive traffic to URLS with the same domain and sub domain (www and non-www subdomain).
Very important!"

Comment: Any answers, please post.